# How to remove only last css rule without effecting any other n last rules beyond that

Tags: html, css

I have following css rules(as seen from chrome inspector):

```
#lemon { //1
    background-image: unset !important;
}
#lemon { //2
    background-image: none !important;
}
#lemon { //3
    background-image: url(stone.png);
}
```

As you can see rule 2 prevents rule 3 from being applied. Hence I added rule 1 but no effect. I know that one way is copying the 2nd last rule(3) and pasting in place of rule1 with *!important*, but is there a generic way of removing only last rule without effecting 2nd or 3rd last rule?

Comment: use pseudo class #lemon:last-child { //your code }

Comment: @VarshaDhadge What will that do? https://jsfiddle.net/rytjL9es/

Comment: @ManojKumar why would anyone will add three different css rule for same element? Unless there are multiple occurrence

Comment: @pebble please add html as well.

Comment: rule 3 and rule 2 are present in external file to which i don't have access. They are kendo files to be exact. kendo uses lot of !important rules hence I need a way to override only-last rule

Comment: In that case add your code in header file or something which is internal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to override an !important without using a second !important. If you don't use important than either the most recent rule or a rule that is more specific will take precedence (inline css will take precedence over all of those). The same rules apply to important, but all of the overriding rules would have to have important in order to override.